# Comparing percentages of a sample to that of the population.

Tags: statistics, sampling, percentages

This might be stupid question, but I'm in this sort of situation:

60% of people in a city have a pet cat, but the national rate is 50%.

So, assuming we have the required bits of information about the population/sample, are there any meaningful ways are there to compare these two percentages?

Answer (score 0):

One direct comparison: an average person in this city is 20% more likely to have a pet cat than the average national